# Problems to get values in combo box

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am using VFP 6.0 and I created a form where I’ve to enter some data thru parent & child tables.  Now according to requirement there are many products under one unique Delivery order. Hence I use a combo box to select product in child record. And according to selected product; I want to have a list of packing in another combo box. But I’m unable to get the list of packing for a particular product in combo box.

Can anyone provide me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the data entry of the combo inside a grid or is it free-form fields on a form?

If in a grid (per each child record), I don't see it happening, even with DynamicCurrentControl of a column.

If a standard form, once you've selected a product, you can use either the VALID or INTERACTIVECHANGE events to query available packing options for the product just selected and bind that result cursor to the data source of the other combobox.  I would actually make this like a custom method of the form so if you are scrolling through the entered child records and needing to constantly refresh the packing combobox, this one method can be called from either the scrolling mechanism, OR from the VALID / INTERACTIVECHANGE event to prevent duplicating same code.

If you have more info, I can obviously adjust this answer.